# Getting a fixed width border when resizing a box in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, resize

I've been building a document in InDesign, and want to collect my text into color-coded boxes and sidebars.

My technique so far: Make a text box. Make a colored rectangle. Size them like I want, drag the text box onto the rectangle and group them.

The problem comes when the text grows or shrinks, and I need to resize its box. The grouped objects rescale in proportion. What I want is a fixed width border around the text box of color. Is there a way to link the text box and the color box such that the color box is always X pixels bigger than the text box, rather than X% bigger than the text box when they're resized together?

Or if there's a better way to accomplish having a color coded box around text with fixed with borders, I'm all ears.

[image: Proportional resize screwin' up mah border area.]

Comment: Oh gad that's a hideous gradient. Don't hold it against me, it was just a quick example I coughed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rectangular shape and a text frame are essentially the same thing under the hood. You can click in a shape with the text tool and it automatically becomes a text frame. (You can turn off this behavior by unchecking `Preferences > Type > Type Tool Converts Frames to Text Frames`.) There is no need to drag or paste a text frame into another frame under normal circumstances, although this does have a use in particular cases, such as when you want diagonal text inside an arbitrary shape.

Do it this way:

- Drag out a text frame in the usual way, with the text tool, and add your text.
- Press Escape to end text editing and make the Selection (black arrow) tool active.
- Fill the text frame with the color or gradient you want to use.
- Use InDesign's Text Frame Options (`Ctl/Cmd-B` or `Object > Text Frame Options...`) to set up the inset value you want from each edge of the frame.

Now, when you resize (not *rescale*) the text frame, the inset values will remain constant.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of creating a text object, try typing into the box object itself and setting the indent values.